# Kubernetes ConfigMap: import from file as many values instead of as one?

Tags: kubernetes

Creating a new ConfigMap from a file:
`kubernetes create configmap foo --from-file=foo`

This is how the ConfigMap looks internally:
`kubernetes get configmaps foo -o yaml`

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  foo: |
    VAR1=value1
    VAR2=value2
```

Then, I use this ConfigMap to create a set of environment variables in the container:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    name: app
  name: app
spec:
  containers:
    - name: app-server
      image: app:latest
      ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
      envFrom:
      - configMapRef:
          name: foo
      command: ["/bin/bash", "-c", "printenv"]
```

When the container command runs, I see the following output for `printenv`:

```
foo=VAR1=value1
VAR2=value2
```

So, an `echo $foo` command in the pod returns:
`VAR1=value1 VAR2=value2`

According to the documentation for ConfigMap with `--from-file`, this is expected behaviour.

What would be a creative way (and the proper place) to somehow get the values of this file available to the pod as individual env variables `VAR1`, `VAR2`, `VAR3`, etc. ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible with the current version (1.6.x) of Kubernetes. As written in the [offical documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/v1.6/#-em-configmap-em-) for `kubectl create configmap`:

> **--from-file:** Key file can be specified using its file path, in which case file basename will be used as configmap key, or optionally with a key and file path, in which case the given key will be used. Specifying a directory will iterate each named file in the directory whose basename is a valid configmap key.

When you want to create a configmap which is used like this, as input for the `envFrom` container configuration you could create it with the `--from-literal` option like this:

```
kubectl create configmap foo --from-literal=var1=value1 --from-literal=var2=value2
```

To still keep the file, you could transform your file into somethings which then runs this command like this:

```
eval "kubectl create configmap foo $(cat foo.txt | sed -e 's/^/--from-literal=/' | tr "\n" ' ')"
```

Along with that maybe checking the outstanding proposals like the [`--flatten` flag proposal on Github](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/37011) are worth your time.

Also keep an eye on the variable naming. iirc `VAR1` and `VAR2` are not valid property names - they have to be lower case which might cause some issues when passing them on.

Comment: Yes! The `--flatten` flag would be ideal. It describes the use case exactly.